# What is the return type of (display 8) ? / What are void-valued expressions?

Tags: types, scheme, lisp, kawa

In the [Kawa](https://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/) implementation of Scheme, the expression

`(null? ())`

obviously returns

`#t` .

But if I type

`(null? (display 8))`

into the interpreter, the output is

`8#f`

So it seems as if `display` is a function that *does* have a side effect, to wit printing the value, and some sort of non-null return value. Hmm. Maybe `(display 8)` returns `8`? After all, both `8` and `(display 8)` show `8` in the interactive interpreter.

So I typed in

`(= 8 (display 8))`

and the response was

```
/dev/stdin:5:6: warning - void-valued expression where value is needed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gnu.math.IntNum.compare(IntNum.java:181)
    at atInteractiveLevel-5.run(stdin:5)
    at gnu.expr.ModuleExp.evalModule2(ModuleExp.java:293)
    at gnu.expr.ModuleExp.evalModule(ModuleExp.java:212)
    at kawa.Shell.run(Shell.java:283)
    at kawa.Shell.run(Shell.java:196)
    at kawa.Shell.run(Shell.java:183)
    at kawa.repl.processArgs(repl.java:714)
    at kawa.repl.main(repl.java:820)
8
```

So, `(display 8)` is not null but it is "void-valued"? What does that mean? Can I check for *void-valued* like I can *null* in Scheme?

Also, why did the `8` appear after the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your inference that `display` is a function that returns a value (in addition to having the side-effect of printing to the current output port). The value this particular invocation of `display` returns, however, is one that the read-eval-print loop simply chooses not to print when it occurs on its own as the result of evaluating an expression.

Kawa has a number of special [constants](https://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Special-named-constants.html); one of these is `#!void`, which is equivalent to the result of evaluating the expression `(values)` (which means "no values at all"). If you get the value `#!void` from the read-eval-print loop, it won't print:

```
#|kawa:1|# #!void
#|kawa:2|# (values)
#|kawa:3|#
```

This is because Kawa's read-eval-print loop [uses `display`](https://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/FAQs.html#idm139760384391168) to print out the value that an expression evaluates to, and `display` will choose to print nothing when given `#!void`.

---

In the specific case of your experiment comparing the behavior of `8` vs `(display 8)`, there is actually a crucial difference in what is happening. when you feed any input to the interpreter, it:

1. reads (and compiles) the input,
2. evaluates the compiled expression to a value, and
3. prints out the resulting value.

So when you feed it `8`, the printing is happening in step 3. When you feed it `(display 8)`, the printing is happening in step 2, and then the printing from step 3 just prints nothing (because the value returned by `(display 8)` is one that the interpreter chooses not to print).

One way to observe this distinction: build a list from the expressions of interest.

```
#|kawa:1|# (list (display 7) 8 (display 9))
/dev/stdin:1:7: warning - void-valued expression where value is needed
/dev/stdin:1:21: warning - void-valued expression where value is needed
7 9 (#!null 8 #!null)
#|kawa:2|#
```

Here we see that during the evaluation step, the interpreter displayed `7` and then `9`, and then built a list of three elements: `#!null`, `8`, and then `#!null` again.

---

The Kawa interpreter also warned us that our code seemed to have problems: the Kawa interpreter is smart enough during the read-and-compile step (which happens *before* the evaluation and printing steps) to analyze the code for potential problems. Here, it says "The result of invoking `display` is not meant to be used as if it were a normal value" (as compared to a number or a string).

So this explains why you see an error message (because it considers the result of invoking `display` to be void-valued), and it knows that the treatment of such values may not match the user's expectations. (it also explains why the number `8` in your example is printed *after* the error message: Because the error message is generated during the "read" step, but the displaying happens during the "evaluation" step, as explained above.

---

Why do I say "the treatment of such values may not match the user's expectations"? Well, from the experiment above where we ran `(list (display 7) 8 (display 9))`, you *might* infer that the result of evaluating `(display 7)` is `#!null`. But this is actually not true!

In Kawa, `#!null` is a special constant, and it is distinct from `#!void`. For some reason, the Kawa interpreter is deciding that when you plug `(display 7)` into a list-constructing expression (or more generally, I think any context expecting a non-void value), that it can throw away the return value of `(display 7)` and plug `#!null` in there instead.

Why do I say this? Well, there is another way to print out values in Scheme: You can use the `write` procedure. The `display` procedure is usually meant for "human (or end-user) readable" output, while the `write` procedure is meant to show more about the structure of the given datum, when available. For example:

```
#|kawa:1|# (display "Hello World")
Hello World
#|kawa:2|# (write "Hello World")
"Hello World"
#|kawa:3|#
```

In the above, `display` threw away the information that I had a string, and just focused on the contents of that string, while `write` told me "we have a string here, it is 11 characters long. Here are its contents."

*SO*, what happens if we `write` the result of invoking `display`?

```
#|kawa:1|# (write (display 8))
8#!void
#|kawa:2|#
```

Here, we got no warning from the read-and-compile step. Instead, it preserved the value of `(display 8)`. So it first evaluated `(display 8)` (printing `8` to the output), then it fed the value produced from that `(#!void)` into the `write` invocation.

(I won't claim that this is the clearest semantics ever. But my inference is that Kawa's [warn-void-used](https://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Options.html#idm139760394665808) is telling us about cases where the compiler is allowed to plug in a `#!null` in place of a `#!void`)

Comment: Can if check for void somehow [like in racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html)? The expression `(void? (display 8))` does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure. If you can convince the interpreter to bind the actual return value of `(display 8)` without triggering the void-valued expression warning, then you should probably be able to use `(equal? #!void bound-variable)`.

Comment: But the problem is that Kawa seems to employ the void-valued expression warning very aggressively. For example, it even issued the warning for *this* code: `(call-with-values (lambda () (display 8)) (lambda l (write l)))`, which seems wrong to me and may be an actual bug.

Answer (score 1):

According to the reports the return value of `display` is undefined. In reality that means there might be an implementation where `(= 8 (display 8))` evaluates to `#t`, but you cannot depend on it.

Most implementations take "undefined" literally and make a value that is their representation of something undefined in the same manner as `#f` is the one  false value in the system. This value would normally not be a number so using `=` which requires all arguments to be numeric will fail and that is what produces the error message, however `(eqv? 8 (display 8)) ; ==> #f` since `display` returns something else than `8` and `eqv?` can compare any values, including the void value.

A nice way to see what it returns is to evaluate `(list (display 8))`. The REPLs of the implementation would suppress the undefined value, but it will most certainly not suppress a list with that same value as the first element.

```
(list (display 8)) ; ==> (#!void) (and prints 8 on the terminal as side effect)
```

I would have preferred the standard to define that the return is to be the argument since then it could have been used for something. After all the input is what is on the stack to begin with so I guess it would not be more effort to do that.